# How do you create an add instruction in an LLVM IR transform pass?

Tags: llvm

I want to replace certain `CallInst`'s in IR with a `ConstantInt` value. In my transform pass, I have been able to identify these `CallInst`'s that I want to replace, and I have created the `ConstantInt` that I want to replace them with.

However, when I try to use `llvm::Value::replaceAllUsesWith(Value* V)` to do the replacement, I get a runtime error saying that the `Value` I want to replace a `CallInst` with is not the same type as the `CallInst` (which makes sense).

My alternate solution is to replace the `CallInst`'s with add instructions that add the constant integer to zero. However, I can't seem to find out how to create an add instruction object in my transform pass. I know that `IRBuilder` has a `CreateAdd` method, but I want to create a standalone instruction, not a new basic block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a add instruction you need to create a `BinaryOperator` documented [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html).

The `BinaryOperator` class offers you some `CreateX` functions as well as a generic Create where you specify the operation you want to create as first argument.

However, I recommend fixing the type problem with your `ConstantInt` first. Assuming your CallInst returns an integer type you can do:

```
CallInst* call = ... // your call
call->replaceAllUsesWith(ConstantInt::get(call->getType(), 0));
```

If it returns something else you can use one of the various casts e.g. a [bitcast](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction) instructions to get matching types.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the error I was seeing was due to the fact that one cannot replace an Instruction with a ConstantInt (which I now know is not true), but it was actually because my CallInst's returned 64-bit integers, but I was trying to replace them with a 32-bit constant integers.

As an aside, how would I create an add instruction? I see `DEFINE_HELPERS (Add, NSW) DEFINE_HELPERS(Add` in the Binary Operator docs, but how do I use that?